# React : Unable to set the values in the form

Tags: reactjs

I want to set the values of the form if the edit is true. I am passing the editable state to true and passing the first element of the array but when the component is mounted it didn't show the 0th element values that were sent from the parent component to the child component.

### Here's the code :

### Milestone.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./milestone.css";
import MileStoneForm from './mileStoneForm'
import {LEFT_ARROW, ROUTES_PATH } from "../../constants";
export default class MilestoneComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                arr: [],
                edit:true
        }
    }
    backPage = () => {
        this.props.history.push(ROUTES_PATH.CREATE_PROJECT)
    }
    handleData=(data)=>{
        const {arr}=this.state
        arr.push(data)
        //localStorage.setItem('mileStoneData',JSON.stringify(arr))
        console.log(arr)
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <div style={{ background: "#F3F3F3", minHeight: "100vh" }}>
                    <div className="header-div">
                        <img
                        src={LEFT_ARROW}
                        alt="back"
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        className="left-arrow-size left-back-btn-bt-mar"
                        onClick={this.backPage}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <MileStoneForm arr={this.state.arr[0]} handleData={this.handleData} edit={this.state.edit}/>
                </div>
        )
    }
}
```

---

MileStoneForm.js

---

```
import { InputBase,Grid,TextareaAutosize} from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { DROP_D } from "../../constants";
import { PRIVATE_SwITCH,PUBLIC_SwITCH } from "../../constants";
import NormalButton from '../../common/component/normalButton';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

class MileStoneForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
                deliverable_name:"",
                due_date:"",
                deliverable_notes:"",
                milestone_based_payment:false,
                deliverable_name_error:"",
                due_date_error:"",
                deliverable_notes_error:"",
                percent_rate:0,
                percent_rate_error:""
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('component did mount')
        if(this.props.edit===true){
            console.log('editable')
            if(this.props.arr){
                console.log('array')
            this.setState({
                deliverable_name:this.props.arr.milestoneName,
                deliverable_notes:this.props.arr.description,
                due_date:this.props.arr.dueDate,
                milestone_based_payment:this.props.arr.isMilestoneBasedPayment,
                percent_rate:this.props.arr.percentageRate
            },()=>{
                console.log('edit')
            })
        }
    }
}
render() {
        const {deliverable_name,deliverable_name_error,deliverable_notes,deliverable_notes_error,
            due_date,due_date_error,milestone_based_payment,}=this.state
        return (
            <>
                <div className="milestone">
                    <div className="milestone-header">ADD MILESTONE</div>
                    <Grid container className="milestone-deliverable-name-date">
                        <Grid item md={6} lg={6} xs={12}>
                            <div className="milestone-deliverable-name">DELIVERABLE NAME</div>
                                
                                    <InputBase
                                    className={`milestone-input-deliverable-name`}
                                    autoComplete={"off"}
                                    placeholder={"MileStone Name"}
                                    onChange={e=>this.handleChange(e,'deliverable_name')}
                                    value={deliverable_name}
                                    maxLength="100"
                                    autoFocus={true}/>
                                    {deliverable_name_error && (
                                        <div className="input-error-style">{deliverable_name_error}</div>
                                    )}
                                
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item md={6} lg={6} xs={12}>
                                        <div className="milestone-due-date">
                                            DUE DATE
                                        </div>
                                        <label>
                                                <DatePicker
                                                dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                                margin="normal"
                                                selected={due_date}
                                                placeholderText="Due Date"
                                                onChange={date=>this.handleChangeDate(date,'due_date')}
                                                maxDate={new Date()}
                                                className={`milestone-input-due-date`}
                                                />
                                                <img src={DROP_D} alt="drop down" style={{cursor:'pointer'}} className='dropdown-milestone'/>                                                        
                                        </label>

                                    {due_date_error && (
                                        <div className="input-error-style">{due_date_error}</div>
                                    )}
                        </Grid>
                    
                        <Grid item md={12} lg={12} xs={12}>
                            <div className="milestone-notes-description">
                                <div className="milestone-deliverable-notes">DELIVERABLE NOTES</div>
                                <div className="milestone-description-notes">Add description below</div>
                                <TextareaAutosize className={`milestone-textarea-description`}
                                onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e,'deliverable_notes')}
                                value={deliverable_notes}/>
                                {deliverable_notes_error && (
                                    <div className="input-error-style">{deliverable_notes_error}</div>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    
                    
                        <Grid item md={12} lg={12} xs={12}>
                                <div className="milestone-payment">MILESTONE BASED PAYMENT?</div>
                                {this.togglePayment()}
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item md={12} lg={12} xs={12}>
                            {milestone_based_payment ?<>
                                <div className="percent-rate">PERCENT RATE</div>
                                    <InputBase
                                    className={`milestone-percent-rate`}
                                    autoComplete={"off"}
                                    placeholder={"20%"}
                                    maxLength="100"
                                    value={this.state.percent_rate}
                                    onChange={(e)=>{this.handleChange(e, "percent_rate")}}
                                    />
                                    {
                                        this.state.percent_rate_error && (
                                        <div className="input-error-style">{this.state.percent_rate_error}</div>
                                        )
                                    }
                                    </> :''}
                        </Grid>
                    
                    
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={4} lg={4}></Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={4} lg={4}></Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={4} lg={4}>
                                <div className={milestone_based_payment?"milestone-button":"milestone-button-margin-btm"}>
                                <NormalButton
                                buttonValue="ADD"
                                className="btn-create-project flex-justify"
                                icon_color="black"
                                handleButtonAction={()=>this.handleSubmit()}
                                />
                                </div>
                            </Grid>
                        
                        </Grid>
                    </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default MileStoneForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating your state with `push`, never do that. You have to create a new state object.

```
handleData=(data)=>{
        const { arr }= this.state
        const nextArr= {...arr, data}
        //localStorage.setItem('mileStoneData',JSON.stringify(arr))
        this.setState({arr: nextArr});
        console.log(arr)
    }
```

The console.log will show the new data anyway, since you are changing that object, but since the object reference will be the same (same object as before), it will not rerender.